# .dropdown-item not firing on touch

Tags: jquery

i have a simple Bootstrap Dropdown with some items which not firing on touch. I want to sort some listitems via isotope.js through this dropdowns.

code

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-orange waves-effect col-12 dropdown-toggle" 
      type="button" 
      id="dropdownMenuButton" 
      data-toggle="dropdown" 
      aria-haspopup="true" 
      aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fas fa-filter mr-2"></i>Filter
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a href="#!" data-filter="*" class="dropdown-item active">Alle</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" id="mobilecategory" data-filter=".Gesundheit"  href="#">Gesundheit</a>
  </div>
</div> 

...

<script>
$('.dropdown-item').on( 'touchstart', function(element) {    //not firing
     element.preventDefault();
     alert('test');    
    $( "a.dropdown-item" ).each(function( index ) {
        $( this ).removeClass('active');
    });
    $(this).addClass('active');
    //var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');

    var filterFns = {
        kSearch: function () {
            return qsRegex ? $(this).text().match(qsRegex) : true;
        }
    };

    var filterValue = selector;

    filterValue = qsRegex ? filterFns['kSearch'] || filterValue : filterValue;

    // use filterFn if matches value
    currentFilter = filterValue;
    $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
</script>
```

Someone have an idea to solve this?

i tried many things like 'click, touch, tap' but nothing of them works.

EDIT: it seems that no click or touch events works correctly on mobile (iphone 7, X)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code. you commented code in wrong way. and touchstart event is only for mobiles. Also include jQuery library to use jQuery

```js
 

  $( document ).ready(function(){
var target = document.querySelector('.dropdown-item');
    target .addEventListener( 'touchstart', function(element) {   
         alert('test');    
        $( "a.dropdown-item" ).each(function( index ) {
            $( this ).removeClass('active');
        });
        $(this).addClass('active');
        //var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
        selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');

        var filterFns = {
            kSearch: function () {
                return qsRegex ? $(this).text().match(qsRegex) : true;
            }
        };

        var filterValue = selector;

        filterValue = qsRegex ? filterFns['kSearch'] || filterValue : filterValue;

        // use filterFn if matches value
        currentFilter = filterValue;
        $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-orange waves-effect col-12 dropdown-toggle" 
      type="button" 
      id="dropdownMenuButton" 
      data-toggle="dropdown" 
      aria-haspopup="true" 
      aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fas fa-filter mr-2"></i>Filter
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a href="#!" data-filter="*" class="dropdown-item active">Alle</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" id="mobilecategory" data-filter=".Gesundheit"  href="#">Gesundheit</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The Desktop event with click is working fine, thatswhy i asking for touch to get it work for mobile phones.

Comment: try this code in your mobile test. I have made some changes

Comment: nothing... the alert() is not coming. i have no idea whats wrong there, in browser works fine in mobile view

Comment: can yo send the link of your webpage so that i can try it in mobile

Comment: i changed the code to the last working version of mobile in Browser. https://www.lopero.de/lokal/unternehmen

Comment: ok its solved. A very stupid thing, but it works now as expected

Answer (score 0):

Its solved.

The error was only on mobile devices so that im looked into the javascript area where i cant inspect on mobile. (desktop no errors in console)
After cleaning all functions of stuff i dont need the error was still there.

Now i wrapped all the code into

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... })
```

and its done. Now it works on mobile without changing of the other stuff.

Hope anyone needs this info as helpful.